# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: android, flutter

I will get the application output, but I am facing the R8 problem. I don't quite understand what should I do? can you help me? I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days, but I couldn't find a way even though I tried every way.

## command:

`flutter build apk --release`

## gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

## build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## Error:

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/cepa/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cab50c2c7ac6b541840b2624ca64ff03/transformed/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.6.21.jar:kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 8s```

How can I resolve this error?
````

Comment: Are you using proguard if so please proguard-rules.pro

Answer (score 0):

Can you open your android project to android studio and update the gradle version as per below version

Build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
```

If it is not workout then please check with disable with minifyEnabled=false and still you get error then post error on chat i will guide you.